# Warning given when running a model: boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

Tags: r, large-data, glm, mixed-models, singularity-container

I am doing following simulation study to observe model performance of sample pooled data from superpopulation data

```
a<-0
beta<-0.5
n<-10^6
probx<-0.5

gamma<-c(rep(x = 0.1,n/5), rep(x = 0.2,n/5), rep(x = 0,n/5), rep(x = -0.1,n/5), rep(x = -0.2,n/5))
      
    x<- rbinom(n,1,probx)
    
    lp.y <- a + (beta+gamma)*x
    
py<- exp(lp.y)/(1+exp(lp.y))

y<- 1*(py > runif(n))

d<-data.frame(x,y)
  
samp.prob.1 <- c(rep(1/1000*(7/4), n/5), rep(1/1000*(5/4), n/5), rep(1/1000*1, n/5), rep(1/1000*(3/4), n/5), rep(1/1000*(1/4), n/5))
    
    
SampleSurvey<-function(data.pop, kN, prop, samp.prob)
{ data.pop$samp.prob <- samp.prob
selc <- sample(1:kN, kN*prop, prob = samp.prob)
      data.survey <- data.pop[selc,]
      data.survey$weights <- 1/data.survey$samp.prob
      return(data.survey)  
    }
   
data.survey.1 <- SampleSurvey(data.pop = d, kN = n, prop = 1/1000, samp.prob = samp.prob.1)
    
data.survey.2 <- SampleSurvey(data.pop = d, kN = n, prop = 1/1000, samp.prob = samp.prob.1)
    
data.survey.3 <- SampleSurvey(data.pop = d, kN = n, prop = 1/1000, samp.prob = samp.prob.1)
    
data.survey.4 <- SampleSurvey(data.pop = d, kN = n, prop = 1/1000, samp.prob = samp.prob.1)
    
data.survey.5 <- SampleSurvey(data.pop = d, kN = n, prop = 1/1000, samp.prob = samp.prob.1)

data.survey.1$cname<- rep("A",1000)

data.survey.2$cname<- rep("B",1000)

data.survey.3$cname<- rep("C",1000)

data.survey.4$cname<- rep("D",1000)
                      
data.survey.5$cname<- rep("E",1000)
    
pooled.survey<- rbind(  data.survey.1,  data.survey.2,  data.survey.3,  data.survey.4, data.survey.5)

pooled.survey1<- rescale_weights(data = pooled.survey, group = "cname", probability_weights = "weights")

mod6 <- glmer(y~x+(1|cname), family= binomial ("logit"), data=pooled.survey1, weights = pweights_a)
```

When I run the mixed effect model, R gives me the warning the singular fit?

Could anybody give me the solution to get rid of the singular fitting?